# Are singletons compact in the discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

> Let $(X, \mathcal{P}(X))$ be a topological space where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the discrete topology on $X$. Is $\{x\} \subseteq X$ compact?

I would think not, since if we take $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $\Phi = \{\{x\}_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{-}}\} \cup \{0\}$ which is the set of all singletons in $\mathbb{R}^{-}$ along with $\{0\}$ is an open cover of $\{0\}$ that contains no finite subcovering.

Is this a correct counterexample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that *does* have a finite subcover - namely, $\{\{0\}\}$ (I think you mean "$\cup\{\{0\}\}$" instead of "$\cup\{0\}$" - if you mean the latter, then that doesn't cover $\{0\}$).

More generally, any finite set is compact in any topological space: if $\{U_i: i\in I\}$ is a cover of $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$, then pick $i_1, ..., i_n$ such that $a_k\in U_{i_k}$; we then have that $\{U_{i_k}: 1\le k\le n\}$ is a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

In the discrete topology **all** sets are open (so all sets are closed).  Therefore, one possible "open cover" of any set is the collection of singleton sets, {a}, for a any member of the set.  From that it follows that a set in the discrete topology is compact if and only if it is finite.

Answer (score 1):

If the topology is discrete then, $A\subseteq X$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is finite. This is true since every $\{x\}$, $x\in X,$ is open.

Hint: $A\subseteq X$ be compact. If $A\subseteq \cup_i \{x_i\}$.